# Why does PyTorch require me to assert integer shapes values as a tuple?

Tags: torch

I believe the shape of this tensor - `torch.Tensor(9)` should be an integer and not a tuple. However, while asserting its shape, torch expects me to assert it as a tuple and not an integer.

Here's my minimal working example -

```
import torch

x = torch.Tensor(3,3)
y = torch.Tensor(9)
print(y.shape)
assert x.shape == (3,3)
#This works
assert y.shape == (9,)

#This fails
assert y.shape == (9)
```